# How can I find the price for NRSA (non-revenue space-available) tickets for Delta?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, online-resources, delta-air-lines, standby

Given a flight route and date/time, how can I find out the price of NRSA (non-revenue space-available) tickets for Delta Air Lines?

Comment: How would this be useful to you unless you are an employee of Delta Air Lines?

Comment: Also, i would be surprised if such arrangements aren't part of an NDA for the employees.

Comment: Doesn't "non-revenue" normally mean that the tickets are free?

Comment: @ajd Theoretically you could use the availability of such tickets as an indication that in general a particular flight is likely to be under booked (as NRSA get loaded after paying pax get loaded).  How knowing that as a pax can help you is .. not clear.

Comment: @ajd NRSA tickets can be used by non-employees. idk about NDA.

Comment: @cpast not always free, idk about the norm.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt sure but you have to know an employee right, and in that case you could just ask them?

Comment: @ajd inconvenient to ask each time, esp. when the time+route depends on the price.

Comment: I now believe the this is an XY problem.  For an airline employee exercising their non-rev benefits (whether for themselves or family/friend) the non-rev travel is technically free.  However they are likely to be eligible for non-airline fees such as departure taxes.  These have nothing to do with non-rev status and will be paid by everyone.  So the question is answerable without reference to non-rev.

Comment: @PeterM Non a XY since the true target question is NRSA prices, but yes perhaps can be obtained via tax/misc fee info (idk if NRSA price == sum of non-airline fee/taxes, if that's the case, then that's a valid answer)

Comment: Are you paying a premium for the ticket, so you're trying to figure out what the mark-up is?

Answer (score 2):

You ask the source of the non-revenue ticket.

It is likely there may be no one set rule on what these might cost - I have talked with employees of an airline in the past (not Delta) and they had different options based on their position and length of service with the airline.  One had immediate family could fly free on standby, another (same airline) had immediate family could fly for 10% of some cost.  Others (with different airlines) had similar arrangements.

Your best (possibly only) source of this information is whoever is arranging the ticket for you.